# Vertical grid/table layout Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to display some JSON data vertically instead of horizontally:

Column1: Value1

Column2: Value2

and so on.

These values are coming from a database and I'll need the ability to scroll through the records being returned from the database.

This is for an MVC3 application using C#, and I'm open to whatever possible solutions are out there.

UPDATE:

While the below wasn't exactly what I needed, it put me on the right path to using a pivot table which I hadn't thought about previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use linq, You convert like this:

```
var pivotTable = from m in db.table
                 select new
                 {
                     Column1 = (from t1 in m
                               where t1.Field == "column1"
                               select t1.Value,

                     Column2 = (from t2 in m
                               where t2.Field == "column2"
                               select t2.Value
                 };

Json(pivotTable, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

First Look:

```
-----------------
  Field | Value |
-----------------
column1 |    14 |
column2 |    34 |
column1 |    14 |
column2 |    36 |
column1 |    18 |
column2 |    34 |
```

After linq query

```
Column1 | Column2 |
-------------------
     14 |      34 |
     14 |      36 |
     18 |      34 |
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't use linq, using a mysql backend and linq takes too long to return the data I need. though you may have put me on the right direction